# Tutorial I followed left '#' in place of links in buttons. How can I fix that if I want to host it on an actual server?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in HTML and CSS and I watched this guy's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdYaIe66b_M&list=PLmFAcHdmOjpKCL1WPzBBmg2OrAuVwF6we&index=1) on how to build a portfolio.

In the 'nav' class, he left the code as such,

```
<div class="nav">
    <a class="a active" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="b"href="#">Gear</a>
    <a class="c" href="#">Colour Dump</a>
    <a class="d" href="#">BnW Dump</a>
</div>
```

The website he is building seems to be more of a local based html file and not meant to be hosted on actual server as there isn't any links in the buttons. How would I go about fixing this? I plan to host the website on an actual web server and I just tested it, the buttons do not lead anywhere due to a lack of buttons.

[Here is a pastebin leading to my html file](https://pastebin.com/9fwx5HBh) and
[one to  my css file](https://pastebin.com/qgJ0zb7B).

My apologies if some of the classes names are misleading (i.e. do not match up to the titles), I was following his tutorial and only edited the details afterwards.

Thank you in advance for any help rendered!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Do not paste the source code you have on an external site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your href links in a navigation will most likely link to another page on your website like this:

```
<div class="nav">
  <a class="a active" href="/about">Home</a>
</div>
```

Another option would be an anchor link. This is the case for example if you have a single page website.

```
<div class="nav">
  <a class="a active" href="#about">Home</a>
</div>
// Jumps to the element with the id="about"
```

If your nav would link to another website it would look something like this

```
<div class="nav">
  <a class="a active" href="https://example.com">Go to Example</a>
</div>
// This link is external
```

Also interesting is to learn about the different attributes for links. You can find a goof read [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: If using plain html files then use `href="/about.html"` or if it is in a directory then `href="/about/company.html"`. It is good practice to use only letters, digits, underscore and the minus character in the filename.